# jquery accordion in a php do while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get this to work in an accordion type of fashion. IE when one #btn_details is clicked, it will toggle to display the info, but when another is clicked it will hide the first and display the other. I am using php in my jquery to uniquely identify the ID for each button and div.

Jquery is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn_details0001").click(function(){

        $("#details_display00001").slideToggle(600);
                });
     });
```

the HTML is below:

```
<div  id="details_display00001" class="no_display">
                <p>Admin Name: Devin</p>
                <p>Admin Email: email@email.com</p>
                <p>Admin Since: 2015-01-01</p>
                <p>Last Modified: 2015-09-03</p>
</div>
<button id="btn_details">details</button>
```

I have displayed them none in CSS

Would I need to use the UI accordion function? Is it possible to add an effect like this onto this?

I am new to jquery and am finding myself at a loss.

I tried adding this to it but to no avail.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        navigation: true
     });
```

Comment: did you look in console for errors ?

Comment: Can you post the output html of your `php`?

Comment: I have edited the code to show no PHP and this is what the outputted HTML will look like